# Question about eligibility trace

Tags: machine-learning, reinforcement-learning

Question 1:

for eligibility formula: $G_t^\lambda = (1-\lambda)\sum^{T-t-1}_{n=1}\lambda^{n-1}G^{(n)}_t+\lambda^{T-t-1}G_t$

I wonder why it is identical to TD(0) when $\lambda=0$, isn't the outcome 0?

Question 2:

It is said that with $\lambda \in(0,1)$,agent would learn better than either extremely way(0 or 1). But why? Is it theoretically proved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ad 1: for $\lambda=0$,
$$
G^{\lambda}_t = G_{t}^{(1)} + G_t
$$
as $0^0=1$, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11150/zero-to-the-zero-power-is-00-1 for details.

Ad 2: It is about balancing between forward and backward TD.

> The forward view tells us how every state is updated, but we would have to wait until the end until we can update anything. The backward view tells us, how we should broadcast the current temporal difference error to previous states.

http://www.shadmehrlab.org/Courses/learningtheory_files/RL3.pptusg=AOvVaw1AIIKjOtjz1JiXXQmm8TjZ

Comment: OP's question 2 is not about forward vs backward view of calculating returns, but about single-step TD vs Monte-carlo, and the finding that in-between values of $\lambda$ (e.g. $\lambda = 0.7$) can offer better performance than either extreme.

Comment: yes, indeed, for one aspect, eligibility trace indeed give a way to better perform multi-step update. But here about Q2 is really about difference between one step(TD(0)) to multi-step and to full step(MC). Here intuitively, I just can't get it why multi-step way is more efficient.

Comment: The multi-step is more efficient especially if you get reward at the end of the episode (finding a treasure). In that situations TD(0) may be updating zeros to zeros for the most of time.

Comment: So this means that the more steps used in an episode, the more data efficient it is when updating states value(as more future rewards are used),leads to less episodes to have proper estimated states value. BUT, the more steps used, the more delayed for updating,which makes data less efficient (high variance low bias),contrary to TD(0)(high bias low variance).     
Now I figure it out : 

MC:updated too rationally but time consuming.
TD(0):updated too quickly but myopic.
TD(λ)： updated balanclly.